# Animación Barra de búsqueda de WhastApp

Tags: java, android, xml, animación

Cómo puedo poner la *animación* como la que tiene *WhatsApp* en su barra de búsqueda al abrirse y cerrarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así tengo mi *animación* actual:

`clase`

```
@Override
public void onSearchViewShown() {
    searchView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Cat_sjl.this, R.anim.rotate_image));
}

    @Override
    public void onSearchViewClosed() {       
     searchView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Cat_sjl.this, R.anim.rotate_image));
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
    }
});
```

`anim`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Si no me equivoco debo cambiar la `anim` y estará listo, pero cuál es la `anim` que necesito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podría crearse con una animación, pero creo que es complicado porque interactua con un par de LinearLayout e imageView. Te recomiendo utilizar lo siguiente:

Hay un repositorio que hace lo que buscas:

[image: MaterialSearchView texto][image: MaterialSearchView voz]

Dale una oportunidad.

Aquí es el repositorio de Github para [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) .

Comment: Curiosamente es el repositorio que uso, pero a mi no me hace ese efecto (que no es el que busco, pero me sirve) @Maguz

Comment: @UserNameYo excelente que ya uses el repositorio! ahora echale un vistaso al MaterialSearchViewStyle y **bonus** y al Override que define

Comment: @UserNameYo si esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, marcala como respuesta correcta para que ayude a otros usuarios que buscan o pasan por lo mismo

Comment: Marco como solucionado! @Maguz no era el efecto exacto que buscaba, pero como nadie más pudo aportar una respuesta, me sirve ese efecto, gracias!